# Pretty URL Conditional Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Our site allows for a pretty url 'etest.me/1234' where '1234' is a client id. As you can see below it redirects to our route.php file where we do our redirect. The problem is when a client uses 'etest.me' without the '/1234' they get the apache 'The requested URL /go/ was not found on this server.' message. I would like the url to go to another page when the '/1234' is missing.

Note that we have the domain and path forwarded to the non-existing '/go' directory so the rules below will catch it. The following is in our .htaccess file in the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
#restrict rewriting URLs ONLY to paths that DO NOT exist
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
# commented out to speed up looking since we are not processig file names anyway
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^go/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ ./route\.php?go=$1
```

Comment: Where you want to redirect in case when there is no `client id`?

Comment: index.php in root directory where .htaccess resides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working perfectly fine for me. Hope this will work for you as well.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^go/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /route.php?go=$1 //when client id exist
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php // when no client id
```

Comment: doesn't work. the directory /go doesn't exist. its only in the forwarded domain etest.me => etesting.io/go where /go is used to trigger the rewrite (as mentioned in the comment above). I don't think I can do it without the forwarded /go

Comment: Or you can try `RewriteRule ^go/([a-zA-Z0-9/]*)$ ./route\.php?go=$1` and handle empty $_GET['go'] in route.php script (change + to *)

Comment: still wants to use the /go 'The requested URL /go/index.php was not found on this server.' need to remove the /go part because there is no /go directory.

Comment: works now. had to change route.php to header('location: ../index.php'); (added the '../' to get out of go dir back into route.

Comment: I think the above will take care of all you need

Comment: It's working. I'm not too familiar with .htaccess files and mod re-wrire. I would like to think there was a more elegant solution for pretty urls but I guess my entire logic isn't too ugly. lol

Comment: No issues.. It takes time to learn, implement and debug which we learn over a time

Comment: I would like to post the entire solution for others to use. can I accept your answer and do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new rule to handle this situation:

```
RewriteRule ^go/$ ./another_script\.php
```

Comment: the directory /go doesn't exist. its only in the forwarded domain etest.me => etesting.io/go where /go is used to trigger the rewrite

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer by Sahil and posted the entire logic below for others to use:

```
Domain: etest.me
Pretty URL: etest.me/1234 (where '1234' is a client id)
Forwarded to: etesting.io/go (with forward path option selected so the '/1234' will be include in the forward)
```

Note: There is no '/go' directory on the server, '/go' is used to trigger the redirect.

Wanted 'etest.me' (without client id) to go to index file in root directory.

Here is the rewrite rules in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^go/([a-zA-Z0-9/]*)$ ./route\.php?go=$1
```

Here is the route.php code:

```
<?php

if($_GET['go']){
    $a = explode('/', $_GET['go']);
    $c = count($a);
    if($c == 1 || $c == 2){
        header('location: ../../index.php?aid=' . $a[0] . '&tid=' . $a[1]);
        exit;
    }
    else{
        die('Invalid URL');
    }
}
else{
    header('location: ../index.php');
    exit;
}
```

And finally the index.php file:

```
if($_GET['aid'] && $_GET['tid']){
    header('location: test/register.php?aid=' . $_GET['aid'] . '&tid=' . $_GET['tid']);
    exit;
}
elseif($_GET['aid']){
    header('location: test/index.php?aid=' . $_GET['aid']);
    exit;
}
else{
    header('location: account/index.php?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    exit;
}
```

Hope this helps somebody in the future.

I would like a more elegant solution but it's behind me for now...